# Need to play video inside tkinter GUI (instead of pop up)

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, imshow

I am using python TKinter in my project (link mentioned below) to create a GUI.  I'm using `imshow('result', frame)` to display a video (sequence of frames). However, a new window pops out to play the video.  How do I display it inside the GUI window itself?

[Project Link](https://github.com/Surveillance-NWB/Surveillance/blob/main/Surveillance.NWB.py)

Comment: `imshow` isn't part of `tkinter`, from what I know. Also showing a video inside a `tkinter` takes a lot of coding.

Comment: @TheLizzard actually coding it in tkinter may crash it since I can't image doing that without using another thread because as far as I know showing a video requires a constant stream of data which would probably block `.mainloop()` if used in the same thread, but then again calling tkinter methods from the other thread (because that would be faster) may break tkinter (btw would calling tkinter methods from another process break it?) actually I am gonna try writing something (something like this)

Comment: @Matiiss For the past 3 weeks I have been trying to program a video player. I find of works (0fps on fullscreen otherwise 25 fps). Basically have 1 thread read the images from the file and use a `tkinter` loop to convert the images to `PhotoImage` then display it.

Comment: @Matiiss Also `pygame` is faster when it comes to displaying images. But my computer still can't resize the images fast enough when on fullscreen.

Comment: @Matiiss Look at [`time.perf_counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter). I used that to get the amount of time that the video has been running. From that I can figure out which frame I am supposed to be showing on the screen. Also my computer isn't fast enough to handle 30 FPS when using `tkinter`.

Comment: If you have VLC player installed, you can try using `python-vlc` module which can embed the video in tkinter frame.